# What value types can the HTML5 placeholder attribute value hold?

Tags: html, browser

What value can the placeholder attribute be: text, number or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just plain text.  You could put any text in there, including a number.  Since its just a placeholder, not a default value, you can even put text as a placeholder in a field you said was `type='number'`.  The placeholder text disappears once the field has focus.

Placeholder Text
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html#placeholder